Show that $\sum_{n \ge 1} (n \log n)^{-(1-\epsilon)}$ with $ \epsilon > 0$ diverges
I think this sum diverges but I can't seem to show it.
$$ \sum_{n \ge 1} (n \log n)^{-(1-\epsilon)}, \ \ \ \epsilon > 0 $$
I have tried using the bound $n \log n = \log n^n < n^n$ which led me to an inconclusive root test.
I also tried $n \log n \leq n(n-1)$ via the known fact $1-x \leq e^{-x}$, but made no progress down this path.
